# Changing the default render path is not working

Tags: rendering, path, windows

I'm trying to change the default render path in Blender 2.9 to something else. I've changed it in the preferences to my D:\ drive.

[image: render path preferneces]

However, after restarting (and rebooting) opening a new scene the path is `/tmp\`

```
print(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath)
```

Is there another setting I'm missing?

Comment: Hello have you saved the preferences?

Comment: @moonboots I have done this, but it never worked for me. Still does not in 3.5.1, the path in the _Output Properties_ can be saved with the startup file, but what sense makes the entry in the preferences then? I also have no idea when or where the Render Cache is used...

Comment: So it may be a bug?

Comment: @moonboots It might be, I never asked if someone else has this problem too, because I usually set individual paths for all my projects.

Comment: @moonboots Yes, I've saved preferences several times. This has been an on-gong issue for me.

Comment: OK I asked because there's an auto-save option but I'm not sure that it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a default path for *newly created Scenes*.
To see it work, create a new *Scene* within your blender file.

(Simply restarting Blender won't show any changes, because it loads your Startup File with the old filepath)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why saving preferences, quitting Blender, re-starting Blender (with a new scene) won't work.

Comment: Hi :). Not sure, it might be a bug in 2.9, but it works just fine in Blender 3.4.

Comment: Also keep in mind that restarting Blender won't automatically create a new scene. It uses your Startup File scene.

Comment: I did not know that you could change the Start Up File scene.

Comment: It's all in the maual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/startup_file.html ;)